# Updating a file based on match in a second file.

Tags: awk

I have two files, key.txt and target.txt, I want to update the target.txt file based on presence/absence of a field within the key.txt file.

key.txt

```
B x001 block134 10 50
B g013 block341 10 70
B x560 block444 30 99
B f777 block878 50 29
```

target.txt

```
h01 x999 3 4
h08 x560 4 7
h14 f777 13 55
j88 h888 15 66
```

output.txt would look like below. It is the target.txt file with an additional column ($5). Where there is no match found between $2 in the target.txt and $2 in  the key.txt then $5=="NM". In the case of a match, the information from $3, $4, and $5 of the key.txt is merged ($3 ":" $4 ":" $5) and placed as $5 in the output.txt.

```
h01 x999 3 4 NM
h08 x560 4 7 block444:30:99
h14 f777 13 55 block878:50:29
j88 h888 15 66 NM
```

Up until now I have been using the following for filtering the file based on a match of $2, but struggling to modify it to actually merge data based on a match.

```
awk 'FNR == NR {keys[$2]; next} $2 in keys' key.txt target.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3":"$4":"$5;next}{$5=(a[$2])?a[$2]:"NM"}1' key.txt target.txt 
h01 x999 3 4 NM
h08 x560 4 7 block444:30:99
h14 f777 13 55 block878:50:29
j88 h888 15 66 NM
```